# Why produce auth.js:65 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, django, ecmascript-6, react-redux, axios

I'm trying to login in my django application using axois and react-redux. My problem is when I entered wrong login information then the LOGIN_FAIL action is work fine but when entered correct login information the LOGIN_SUCCESS action is not work and produce the following error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined". I am confused!! I have also tried to login using postman and it's working fine. How can I solve this problem? Can anyone solve my problem?
Thanks in advance.

Here is my action code:

```
import axios from "axios";
import {
  errorMessage
} from "./messages";
import {
  USER_LOADING,
  USER_LOADED,
  AUTH_ERROR,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  LOGIN_FAIL
} from "./types";

// Login User
export const login = (username, password) => dispatch => {
  // Headers
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json"
    }
  }

  // Request body
  const body = JSON.stringify({
    username,
    password
  });

  axios.post("/api/auth/login", body, config)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        action: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data
      });
    }).catch(err => {
      dispatch(errorMessage(err.response.data, err.response.status));
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_FAIL
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your response what you getting from server? "/api/auth/login"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the header "content-type" to "Content-Type"

```
// Headers
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
```

Finally change "action" to "type" inside your axios then block

```
axios.post("/api/auth/login", body, config)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data
      });
```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to do JSON.stringify.

```
const body = {
    username,
    password
};
```